# Select multiple checkboxes using angularjs but unable to get selected one

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I am trying to get the list of selected checkboxes using angularjs. But unable to get selected.

HTML code Here

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="x in result">
    <div class="item-image">
        <input type="checkbox" id="product_{{x.id}}"  class="form-control" ng-model="x.Selected">
    </div>
    <div class="item-name">
        {{ x.category_name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

script code:

```
.controller('categorieCtrl', function($scope, $http) {  
   $scope.result = [{
            id: 1,
            category_name: 'Apple',
            Selected: false
        }, {
            id: 2,
            category_name: 'Mango',
            Selected: false
        }, {
            id: 3,
            category_name: 'Orange',
            Selected: false
        }];

 $scope.myFunc = function () {
     debugger;
     var message = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                if ($scope.result[i].Selected) {
                    var id = $scope.result[i].id;
                    var categoryName =  $scope.result[i].category_name;
                    message += "Value: " + id + " Text: " + categoryName + "\n";
                }
            }
        alert(message);
    };
});
```

In the above code i am not getting selected items. Please let me know how can i get selected items using angularjs.

Comment: I don't see any problems with [your code](https://plnkr.co/edit/Wl1f94jb5MqsdU7Q3Tet?p=preview). Can you explain what doesn't work as intended?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a plunkr with your code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/SYGvz1qLmv5bgGHAta1L?p=preview) and it is working fine. I suppose you are not calling `myFunc()` correctly.

And also instead of using

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if ($scope.result[i].Selected) {
      ...
  }
}
```

You can make use of `angular.forEach` which will give you the object directly

```
angular.forEach(($scope.result, function(result, index){
  if (result.selected){
     ...
 });
```